# Top Navigation not displaying correctly in Search Centre

Tags: permissions, search-center

I have amended the navigation in the Enterprise Search Centre to inherit the Global Navigation of my Site Collection.

I have recently found out that the navigation in the Search Centre for authenticated  users is not picking up the CSS styling (see attachments). Authenticated Users all have Read Only access.

If I grant them Full Control to the Search Centre then the navigation displays correctly. So I can only assume that this is a permissions issue of some kind.

Does anyone have any ideas what I need to do?

[image: Search Navigation displayed incorrectly]
[image: Search Navigation displayed correctly]

Kind regards,
Nigel